# ERROR 1071 (42000)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name_index ON domains(name);
```

But when I do, I get the error below.

```
ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

I tried to edit the config file but I am not winning, any ideas what to do?

My config file looks like this

```
# * Character sets
#
# MySQL/MariaDB default is Latin1, but in Debian we rather default to the full
# utf8 4-byte character set. See also client.cnf
#
character-set-server  = utf8mb4
collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci
```

Is there anything that I need to change here with regards to the character set?

Comment: Modifying the character set won't make the field that you're trying to index shorter. It may be better to create a non-unique index using a prefix of the field?

Comment: Can you give me an example perhaps ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty reputable answer for this on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes). Generally you'll have better luck with database questions over there.